# removing elements from href python '#'

Tags: python, href

I am looking to remove href elements from the following code, I am able to return the results when I run but it will not remove the '#' and '#contents' from the list of urls in python.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html'
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
links_with_text = []

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True): 
      if a.text: 
          links_with_text.append(a['href'])
      elif a.text:
          links_with_text.decompose(a['#content','#'])

print(links_with_text)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! `list.decompose` is not a function, and that's a good thing because `elif a.text` is unreachable (same condition as `if a.text`). You can use `if a.text and not a['href'].startswith("#"):` to skip hashtag links, but what are you trying to accomplish here beyond that? Please post expected output. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Thanks for the feedback! I am looking to return a list of urls and remove elements such as '#contents' so that the list only returns urls. The final output should be a list of url's.

Comment: OK--I notice there is a `"/"`. Do you want that removed too?

Comment: Yes the "/" also needs removed.

Comment: Are there specific urls you are actually after? A section or something on the page? There is likely a more efficient way to do this, Or do you only want those starting with http/https?

Comment: What attempts have you made at debugging? Have you done any research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`string#startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) to blacklist any links starting with a `"#"`, or whitelist anything starting with `"http"` or `"https"`. Since there are hrefs like `"/"` in your data, I'd use the second option.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
links_with_text = []

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True): 
      if a.text and a['href'].startswith('http'):
          links_with_text.append(a['href'])

print(links_with_text)
```

Note that `list.decompose` is not a function (and this branch of the program is unreachable anyway).

Comment: Thank you ggorlen for your helpful response!

Answer (score 1):

If  you only want https/http links use the inbuilt css filtering via href attribute selector with starts with operator. 'lxml' is also a faster parser if installed.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')
links = [i['href'] for i in soup.select('[href^=http]')]
```

Comment: Thank you QHarr for the helpful response!

Comment: you are most welcome. If you need a more specific subset let us know.